# Non-zero exit status 1 in python -m venv

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

I am currently following this [Beeware Tutorial](https://docs.beeware.org/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial-0.html). The creation of a folder and navigating to it wasn't a problem:

```
C:\...>md beeware-tutorial
C:\...>cd beeware-tutorial
```

When I first entered the following code: `C:\...>python -m venv beeware-venv` it returned the following:

```
Error: Command '['C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\beeware-tut\\beeware-venv\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 3221226505.
```

After I tried the exact same command again, the result was different:

```
Error: Command '['C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\beeware-tut\\beeware-venv\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

My Python version: `Python 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

My pip version: `pip 23.1.2 from E:\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)`

I tried running the command a few more times, but it doesn't change the error code now.

I didn't find anything about such error in the [Documentation](https://briefcase.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and I couldn't find any related questions on here.

**Edit/Answer**

I tried [phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd)'s suggestion, `python -m virtualenv beeware-venv`, and it worked.

Then I was able to access it after writing `beeware-venv\Scripts\activate`.

Comment: The error message is not from Beeware, it's from `python -m venv`. Try `virtualenv` instead. Show us full tracebacks if there will be errors.

Comment: Writing `virtualenv` instead of `venv` worked for me. Thanks!